# JSON Schema : External JSON Schema file is not validating json

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I am trying to validate json with json schema, problem is i have created different json schema files for complex object. I need to include in to main schema using ref tag. and trying to validate my json using everit lib. schema got loaded but when i trying to validate my sample json it is not validating inner schema object.

InnerObject.json

```
   {
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {},
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "typeCode": {
            "$id": "/properties/typeCode",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
            "$id": "/properties/description",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "expDate": {
            "$id": "/properties/expDate",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "issuingCountry": {
            "$id": "/properties/issuingCountry",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "typeCode",
        "description",
        "expDate",
        "issuingCountry"
    ]   
}
```

OuterObject.JSON

```
    {
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
    },
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "$id": "/properties/firstName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "$id": "/properties/lastName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "innerObject": {
            "$id": "#item",
            "type": "object",
            "$ref": "file://com/mypack/innerObject.json"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "firstName",
        "lastName",
        "innerObject"
    ]
}
```

Both files are inside my project src/main/resource

I have json validator class which is use to test my schema.

```
import org.everit.json.schema.Schema;
import org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class JSONSchemaValidator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject jsonSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(JSONSchemaValidator.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/com/schema/outer.schema.json")));
        JSONObject outerJson = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject innerJson = new JSONObject();

        innerJson.put("expDate", "expDate");
        innerJson.put("typeCode", "typeCode");

        outerJson.put("firstName", "firstName");
        outerJson.put("lastName", "lastName");

        outerJson.put("innerObject", innerJson);

        Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(jsonSchema);

        System.out.println(schema.getDescription());
        schema.validate(outerJson);

        System.out.println("done");

    }
}
```

Its validating 1st level using schema but not for inner level. can any one suggest what is did wrong, so that its not validating the json.

Sample JSON which i am trying to validate is :

```
{"firstName":"firstName","lastName":"lastName","innerObject":{"expDate":"expDate","typeCode":"typeCode"}}
```

It should thrown an error as "typeCode" "description","expDate",issuingCountry" 4 fields are mandetory and in input i am passing only two. so for remaining two it should thrown an error.

Comment: Can you provide the json instace you're trying to validate, outside of the java please? That way, I can check what's happening with the validation process using a different tool.

Comment: And, you need to specify if you expect validation to pass or fail with your given schema, as that is currently unclear. Thanks =]

Comment: Changed the question, added test case which i am trying to run and sample json.

Comment: OK, it looks like the schema and validation process is correct. Possible issue is you've got the same `$id` for both schema files. They should be different (and certainly not example..). The validator may have some issues resolving the references because of this reason.

Comment: Also, does it say in the library documentation that it is able to resolve references using a file? If so, I can't find any mention. (resolving `file:` is not something that is defined by the JSON Schema specification)

Comment: I provided relative path also, but not working. do you have any sample example?

Comment: mmmm thing is, the schema file doesn't know anything about where it is, according to the spec. Usually, either the $ref is a full URL, or, the library allows you to load in a schema for a specific given $id. Here's an example from ajv's documentation https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#combining-schemas-with-ref

Comment: "innerObject": {
   "$ref": "file:///C:/innerObject.json"
  } I change definition in outer.json file and added hard corded path and its working... now i am not able to figure it out one thing. instead of hard code path can we do relative path.. i tried all possible combination for relative path...

Comment: For that, you would have to look at the library documentation, as this is non standard JSON Schema behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide inner json file in outer json with ref tag.

for example :

```
{
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
    },
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "$id": "/properties/firstName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "$id": "/properties/lastName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "innerObject": {                
            "$ref": "innerObject.json"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "firstName",
        "lastName",
        "innerObject"
    ]
}
```

In Java code  you need to set resolutionScope, you need to provide path of your inner json.

```
String path="file:" + Paths.get("").toUri().getPath() + "PATH_OF_YOUR_JSONSchema";
        System.out.println("older"+ path); 
        if (path.contains(" ")) {
             path=path.replaceAll(" ", "%20");           
         }
SchemaLoader sl=SchemaLoader.builder().schemaJson(jsonSchema).resolutionScope(path ).build();
Schema schema=sl.load().build();
schema.validate(yourJsonObject);
```